# Flutter crashes during `flutter doctor`

Tags: android, flutter, crash

My setup

- macOS Mojave
- Xcode 10.3
- Android Studio 3.5 with latest SDK and NDK.

I recently upgraded flutter from 1.7.8 to 1.9.1+hotfix, but the immediate 
`flutter doctor -v` crashes in the middle, giving this Terminal output.

```sh
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G95, locale en-CA)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.2 at /Applications/Android/flutter
    • Framework revision 2d2a1ffec9 (8 days ago), 2019-09-06 18:39:49 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0

⣽Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Future already completed
#0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:39:31)
#1      _NativeSocket.startConnect.<anonymous closure>.connectNext.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:523:23)
#2      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:878:14)
#3      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:885:12)
#4      _NativeSocket.multiplex (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:906:11)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

Did anyone see this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should always run the flutter command to avoid returning errors when you run the flutter doctor command. had the same issue and when i did this it worked perfectly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

First run: 
`flutter config --clear-features`

then
`flutter config --no-analytics` and `flutter update-packages`

if all goes like ok, you can run `flutter doctor` nicely.